# Giving Helm chart dependency repository as URL

Tags: kubernetes-helm

I am building a pipeline that will be used to launch a number of helm charts in different environments. The main Helm (v3.0.2) Chart for this has a number of dependencies that can be found in the *stable* helm repository. This is added in all environments but, for reasons that I will spare you from, they have been added with different names.
According to the [Helm documentation](https://helm.sh/docs/topics/charts/#the-chartyaml-file) you should be able to define the *repository* either by name or by URL, as long as it is still added to your helm repo list.
However, if I try that and run `helm dependency update myHelmChart` I get a *could not find chart error*.

**Example:**

Env1:

```
$ helm repo list
NAME        URL                                              
stable      https://kubernetes-charts.storage.googleapis.com/
```

Env2:

```
$ helm repo list
NAME        URL                                              
cf_stable   https://kubernetes-charts.storage.googleapis.com/
```

Chart.yaml

```
...
dependencies: 
  - name: nginx-ingress
    version: 1.37.0
    repository: https://kubernetes-charts.storage.googleapis.com/charts
  - name: ......
```

Now running the dependency update in *Env1* looks like this:

```
helm dependency update myHelmChart
Hang tight while we grab the latest from your chart repositories...
...Successfully got an update from the "stable" chart repository
Update Complete. ⎈Happy Helming!⎈
Saving 1 charts
Downloading nginx-ingress from repo https://kubernetes-charts.storage.googleapis.com/charts
Save error occurred:  could not find : chart nginx-ingress not found in https://kubernetes-charts.storage.googleapis.com/charts
Deleting newly downloaded charts, restoring pre-update state
Error: could not find : chart nginx-ingress not found in https://kubernetes-charts.storage.googleapis.com/charts
```

If I change the Chart.yaml to hold `repository: "@stable"` it will run fine in *Env1* but will fail in *Env2*. What am I doing wrong? How can I solve this so I don't have to rely on all environments using the exact same repo names?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that even though the documentation states that the URL should include */charts* and typing *https://kubernetes-charts.storage.googleapis.com/index.yaml* in a browser redirects to *https://kubernetes-charts.storage.googleapis.com/charts/index.yaml* and retrieves the file, directly using the */charts/index.yaml* extension does not retrieve the file.

The solution was to remove the */charts* extension from my repository URL.
**This may not be the case for all repositories so you may need to test them manually to get the correct path.**